# new line doesn't appear when using c out tag

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I appended "\n" to the String and when using s tag textarea, the newline has been appended and data are shown line by line. But when I use c out tag, data are shown in one line. How can I show line by line using with c out tag?

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (MyBean bean : beanList) {

                sb.append((bean.getName());
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            return sb.toString();
```

JSP

```
<c:out value="${myData}"/>
```

Comment: Did you look at the page source in the browser? You will probably have to use <br/> so the browser will do what you want to do here. Alternatively you might use <pre><c:out value="${myData}"/></pre>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

JSP produces HTML. In HTML, new lines are to be represented by the `<br>` element, not by the linefeed character. Even more, if you look in the average HTML source, you'll see a lot of linefeed characters, but they are by default not interpreted by the webbrowser at all.

Apart from using the HTML `<br>` element instead of the linefeed character,

```
sb.append("<br />");
```

and printing it without `<c:out>` like so `${myData}`, you can also use the HTML `<pre>` element to preserve whitespace,

```
<pre><c:out vaule="${myData}" /></pre>
```

or just apply CSS `white-space:pre` on the parent element, exactly like the HTML `<textarea>` element is internally doing:

```
<span style="white-space:pre"><c:out value="${myData}"/></span>
```

*(note: a `class` is more recommended than `style`, the above is just a kickoff example)*

The latter two approaches are recommended. HTML code does not belong in Java classes. It belongs in JSP files. Even more, you should probably actually be using JSTL `<c:forEach>` to iterate over the collection instead of that whole piece of Java code.

```
<c:forEach items="${beanList}" var="bean">
    <c:out value="${bean.name}" /><br />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: `<span style="white-space:pre"></span>` that was good. Saved me some searching.

Comment: In my case, what I needed was `white-space:pre-line`. Thanks for making me aware of this property :)