# Protecting from XSS and using c:out jsp tag

Tags: java, jsp, xss

A ${book.description} variable contains text with "\n" character incide, so I replace it to html tag to preserve new line (new paragrapf line) in jsp output.
But in this case there is a danger of execution of the XSS code. Is there a way do it using c:out jsp tag and preserv new line in text? If I use c:out for output then all < br/ >replaced to & lt; br / & gt; and there is no new line.

```
<c:set var="newline" value="<%= \"\n\" %>" />           
<p>${fn:replace(book.description, newline, "<br />")}</p>
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514440/new-line-doesnt-appear-when-using-c-out-tag

Comment: It's slightly different problem...

Comment: But solution is same.

Comment: well, but what will happen if there will be XSS code in ${book.description} ?

Comment: You need wrap it with <c:out> tag

Comment: we need to kill two birds with one stone: preserv new line in text and protect from XSS

Comment: If I wrap second piece of code with <c:out> tag then in html page will be & lt; br / & gt; instead of break tag.

Comment: don't use fn:replace. Just put your text as is to <c:out>. To preserve newlines use solution from linked question.

Comment: Thanks, turbanoff. It works.

Comment: p.s. блин, надо было раньше заглянуть в твой профиль :-)

Comment: @turbanoff unfortunately, that solution also prevents the browser from performing line breaking on the text. Braj's suggestion below is better.

Comment: @Jules, that solution does not prevent the browser from performing line breaking on the text. That was the goal - do not prevent line breaking and it works for me.

Comment: @Andy I meant automatic line breaking, as the browser usually does.  See http://jsfiddle.net/U4g3c/ which is simulating what the output from the suggested code might look like.

Comment: @Jules, http://jsfiddle.net/U4g3c/7/

Answer (score 0):

You might interested in other functions of [JSTL Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html).

Have a look at `${fn:escapeXml(text)}` that escapes XML characters in a string. Here is the [Sample](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_replace.htm).

---

Have a look at

```
<c:out value="value" [escapeXml="{true|false}"] [default="defaultValue"] />
```

Read more tutorial on [Core Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html)

---

#### EDIT

Solution 1

```
<c:set var="newline" value="\n" />
<c:set var="text" value="abc\nlmn\nxyz" /> 
${ fn:replace(text, newline,'</br>')}
```

Solution 2

```
<c:set var="newline" value="\n" />
<c:set var="text" value="abc\nlmn\nxyz" /> 
<c:out value="${ fn:replace(text, newline,'</br>')}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

output:

```
abc
lmn
xyz
```

Comment: I do not think this is a better solution. Using of this option will open up the posibbility of execution XSS code on the client.

Comment: No, it won't.  `${fn:replace(fn:escapeXml(text), "\n", "<br/>")}` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Andy combine `c:out` along with `fn:escapeXml` for e.g. try     `<c:out value="${fn:escapeXml(fn:replace(text,'\n','</br>'))}"/>`

Comment: failed to parse that expression

Comment: no of these works? I have not tested it, just typed here directly. You have to do some study on how to use JSTL and EL. I have already shared you some useful links. Have you read all?

Comment: in any case, the solution using style is simpler

Comment: Go ahead if it works. I don't know what style are you talking about?

Comment: If you have tried all the possible solutions and still it's not working then wait for some time to answer it by experts.

Comment: <c:set var="newline" value="<%= \"\n\" %>" />
<c:set var="text" value="${book.description}" />
<c:out value="${fn:escapeXml(fn:replace(text, newline,'</br>'))}"/>   

it makes output & lt; /br & gt;